# Wildfly 10 : ear, ejbs and restful-services

Tags: rest, maven, jersey, wildfly, wildfly-10

I am running into trouble when shifting the dependencies for my restful-services.
After shifting out the dependencies for my restful services using this construct.
The below is a part of my web-module.

**web.xml**

```
   <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>se.nrm.bio.mediaserver.rs</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
            <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

**Java-Class**

```
@Path("/upload")
public class Service {

    private final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Service.class);

    @EJB
    private ServiceBean bean;

    public Service() {
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/isOK")
    public Response isOK() {
        logger.info("@GET /isOK");
        logger.info("ServiceBean is "+bean);
        return Response.status(200).entity("service ok").build();
    }

   @POST
   @Path("/other")
   @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
   public Response uploadAllFiles(
        @FormDataParam("fileName") String fileName,
        @FormDataParam("owner") String owner,
        @FormDataParam("content") final InputStream inStream) {
```

The web-service works when I run it in its own project and deploy it.
When I link the web-service into my 'maven-multi-module'-project and replace the current web-module the EJBs are not injected (getting 'null' in my logger in the **~/isOK** service)

Looking closer into the ear-file and into  wildfly-admin interface.
 I can see that the structure of the ear-file is there and it looks correct, the wildfly-admin reveals my beans.
Am I messing this up by relying on the `org.glassfish.jersey` dependencies here
I am reaching the service **~/isOK** but when I call the **~/other** I get the following stacktrace. Is this a dead end, do I have to use another approach when it comes to a restful-solution when it comes to getting hold of the bean ? (I have my db-connection in that bean)

( a note: I have found a multiple examples of restful-clients out there and some restful-services [MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA] - but I am having trouble finding an example-services & an example-client both written in Java and I truly need that .... because I am calling the service from another java-application. All the books find seem to be quite old now. )

```
ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-13) UT005023: Exception handling request to /MediaServerResteasy/rest/upload/other: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:423)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:386)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:334)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:221)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
```

My multi maven structure seems to work, so this is my challenge right now.
I hope this example seems interesting to you, I hope that some of you have run into the same issue and solved this - uploading a file with some attributes.

best, i

Answer (score 0):

So several things here.  The first is that if you're using Wildfly you can code for a standard JAX-RS environment - you don't need to directly involve anything with Jersey.  Change your `pom.xml` to remove all of the dependencies you show and have it only be dependent on:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>7.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

as Wildfly 10 is mostly an EE 7 compatible environment.  Consider upgrading to a newer Wildfly soon though as Wildfly 10 is pretty old.

Now, remove everything related to Jersey from your `web.xml`.  This may mean that the `web.xml` is basically empty.  That's fine other than you may want to keep it to indicate which servlet spec you're using.  I use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
</web-app>
```

which would be the EE 7 version.  Note that it's basically empty.  To specify the root path of your web services, you need a single class:

```
@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class RestApplicationConfig extends Application {
    // intentionally empty
}
```

anywhere in your source code.  This is, again, standard JAX-RS.

You can use the `@EJB` annotation but I tend to use the more modern `@Inject`.  They are basically the same but `@Inject` can bring in a more things than just EJB's.

I would start there and make sure things are working the way you expect.  If you're still having a problem with the `MULTIPART_FORM_DATA` then I'd create a new post with both sides of the code.